# I seem to suck at figuring out how to put a password in

Tags: password

I need some help. I can't access synaptic package manager because it wants a password and I never set a password. I am not a programmer and no longer have anyone but this site to help me figure out how to operate ubuntu. I guess the real learning starts here anyways. 
How do I access my password?

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu requires you to set a password when you installed it, do you remember what password you used to log in?

Answer (score 1):

Type `passwd` in terminal to set a password.

Comment: It will say authentication manipulation error. I will type in passwd and it asks for current unix password and says password unchanged and then brings me to then type something else. What is that else? What should I do?

Comment: So you entered the current password when you were asked and tried to change it to the same password? This won't work. You would have to change it to a new one and then change it back.
But you said you have no password? So did you just press enter everytime?